# Elimination question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been trying to solve this for a while. I'm usually pretty good at this kind of thing but for some reason I can't do decimals. Here's where I got to (there's more to the question but I already finished that part):

$$0.65\times p+0.45\times q=p \tag 1$$

$$0.35\times p+0.55\times q=q \tag 2$$

I'm trying to find the values of $p$ and $q$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please work on your spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 3):

$(1)\quad 0.65p+0.45q=p \iff (-p + 0.65 p) + 0.45 q = 0 \iff -0.35 p + 0.45 q = 0$

$(2) \quad  0.35p+0.55 q = q \iff 0.35 p + (0.55 q - q) = 0 \iff 0.35 p + -0.45 q = 0$

Add the equations. You'll obtain $0 = 0$ which is true, regardless of the values for $p, q$. That is, whatever $p$ you choose, there will be a $q$ that satisfies both equations. Or vice-versa. So there are infinitely many solutions $(p, q)$.

Another way to look at this is to note that really, essentially, both equations say the same thing. To see this, multiply both sides of equation $(1)$: $-0.35 p + 0.45 q = 0$, by $-1$, and you'll obtain equation $(2)$.

Indeed, if you add both equations, as they were originally posted, you get on the left-hand side: $0.65 p + 0.35 p + 0.45 q + 0.55 q = p + q$. And on the right-hand side, you get $p + q$. $p +q = p+q$ no matter what the choices for $p$ and $q$, so again, there are infinitely many solutions for $p, q$.

Comment: It appears you are a less-vocal adherent to BrianM.Scott's philosophy regarding PSQs. I'm interested in your reasoning on that matter.

Comment: @dfeuer: What are PSQs?

Comment: I have written answers to questions that read like Greek. There can be all sorts of reasons for this. We have even had questions posted in other languages and the folks on MSE translate it. I have asked for a question wizard to walk people with a low rep through the minimum expected inputs for writing questions, but that has gone no where. In my opinion, this gives responders every right to post an answer if they feel they understand what is being asked. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti, I'm not challenging her. I'm just curious what *her* reasons are. Also, I have nothing against questions posed in various languages. Finally, I've also answered some pretty badly posed questions, but I tend to feel guilty about it so *you should too* (or not).

Comment: amWhy, you might want to expand this to say why the fact that the sum gives nothing useful leads to the conclusion. It's true, but not necessarily obvious at this level.

Comment: @dfeuer: I appreciate the fact that you want to improve this site, many of us do. I believe we have become a competitive answer mill on many levels and that is the wrong mission. I have always felt that most of are here because we love math; moreover, we love to help newcomers and pros alike to become better at how they approach problem solving, communications and discourse. Unfortunately, what I am seeing is painting an entirely different picture. Regards!

Comment: @Amzoti, I do indeed try. I really like when I'm able to help someone learn something. There's a constant tension between the local and global impacts of every little decision that is frustrating (also see my edited comment).

Comment: @dfeuer: I much prefer that approach and applaud that! Trust me when I tell you that many of us have and do feel a lot of frustration with the local and global things, the negativity, accusatory tone and all the rest. I do not believe this should be what this community portrays itself as. There are a lot of ways of being stern/impactful without being hurtful and many people would learn a valuable life lesson by thinking about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solve equation 1 for one variable (let's say $p$). Then plug $p$ into equation 2 to get the value for $q$. Then plug the value of $q$ back into equation 1 to get the value of $p$.

Comment: That won't work here: you will not obtain a "value for q." You'll obtain the truism $0 = 0$ or $q = q$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't read the equations carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your equations are

$.65p+.45q=p$ (Eqn. 1)

$.35p+.55q=q$ (Eqn. 2)

You say your difficulty arises from dealing with decimals. To overcome such difficulty, I recommend defining variables for "nasty decimals", solving for your desired variables, and then plugging in the values for decimals when the dust settles on one side of an equation.

To demonstrate this procedure, we transform your equations into the following:

$$ ap+bq=p \\ cp+dq =  q$$ where $a=0.65, b=0.45, c=0.35, d=0.55$. Note that none of these variables is equal to $0$, so we have the ability to divide by any of the variables $a,b,c,$ or $d$ in any of the following steps.

Let's solve the first equation for $q$:

$$ ap+bq=p \\ bq = p-ap \\ bq = p(1-a) \\ q = p\frac{(1-a)}{b}$$
Plugging in the values of $a$ and $b$ reveal:
$$q = p\frac{(1-a)}{b} \\ q = p\frac{1-0.65}{0.45} \\ q = p\frac{0.35}{0.45} \\ q = \frac{7}{9}p \\ q = ep$$ where $e=7/9$

Let's manipulate Equation 2 only *after* replacing every $q$ we see with a value in terms of $p$:
$$cp+dq=q \\ cp+d(ep) = (ep) \\ p(c+de) = p(e) \\ c+de = e$$ Notice that $p$ has disappeared from the equation because it can be divided from both sides. Plugging in the values of $c$, $d$, and $e$ we get:
$$c+de=e \\ 0.35+(0.55)\left(\frac{7}{9}\right) = \frac{7}{9} \\ \frac{35}{100}+\frac{77}{180} = \frac{7}{9} \\ \frac{7}{9} = \frac{7}{9}$$

This expression about the fraction 7/9 is true, but what does it tell us about a particular value for $p$ or $q$? Absolutely nothing! Because of this, you can pick *any* value in the world for $p$ and then $q$ will change itself to make the equations work out. Alternatively, pick *any* value for $q$ and then $p$ will change itself to satisfy the equations. So the moral of the story is that even with 2 equations and 2 unknowns, there might be an infinite number of solutions for those equations if those equations have certain properties discussed in linear algebra.

But this is all very unsatisfying since we still can't report to anyone what $p$ and $q$ are. So I say: pick an easy value for either $p$ or $q$ and solve for the other. Let $p=0$. Then equation 1 becomes $$ap+bq=p \\ a(0)+bq = (0) \\ bq = 0 \\ q = 0$$ So we can safely say that $(p,q) = (0,0)$ is a valid solution here. All without using those "nasty decimals" from earlier! :)